# onclick in javascript makes active in css

Tags: javascript, css, function, onclick

I have a little content slider in css and I have two little points that change the image when they are in hover mode.

My question is how can I make the slide stay active by onclick

At the moment, my script looks like this but I think there is a problem with the `add`:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var button = document.getElementsByClassName("dia");
        button.classList.add('active');
    }
```

thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection of HTML elements i.e.  it returns an array-like collection of elements. Iterate over it like you would with a real array.

You have to select a singular element to modify its `classList`. Hence, `document.getElementsByClassName("dia")[0]`, which will pick the first element whose class matches with `dia`. And then you can `add` or `remove` from the `classList` of `button`.

Change your code to this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var button = document.getElementsByClassName("dia")[0];
    button.classList.add('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jquery .addClass() function.

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_addclass.asp

In your case:

```
function myFunction() {
  var button = document.getElementsByClassName("dia");
  button.addClass("active");
}
```

Or now that you're using jquery:

```
function myFunction() { 
  $('.dia').addClass("active");
}
```

Comment: The OP has asked for a simple Javascript solution. Thrusting a framework like jQuery onto him is a bad idea.